# blender render side tab

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine

One of my friends' side tab disappeared. Does anyone know how to get it back?[image]

Answer (score 2):

Just find one of the corners in the view port, and click and drag it inwards. Then change the editor to "Properties".

[image]